# Groupby and filter with dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I want to use dask to make a groupby.
Using pandas I would have to write this to make a basic a basic group by and filter.
My dataset contains 2 indexes : ORDER_ID and PROD_ID. Each ORDER defined by ORDER_ID, we can have 1 or more product defined by its PROD_ID.
My objective is to remove ORDER_ID that contain 1 product.

Using pandas I can do it this way:

```
df = df.groupby('ORDER_ID').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)
```

I didn't find any suitable solution with dask.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html discusses the issues with pandas and dask.

> For data that fits into RAM, Pandas can often be faster and easier to
> use than Dask DataFrame. While “Big Data” tools can be exciting, they
> are almost always worse than normal data tools while those remain
> appropriate.

So this task is not working in pandas as it takes too much memory?

Comment: with pandas it doesn't work. It work with much more RAM. I was not interrested initially by dask

Comment: If the data does not fit into memory for the groupby then use https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-large-datasets-in-python-with-pandas-and-dask-34f43a897d55